# placing a UIToolbar over the Keyboard in Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitoolbar

This is my first post and I am quite new to programming in the iOS.  I am using xcode 4.3 and have what is probably an easy question.  I have looked all over for a way to place a toolbar above the keyboard that has a prev/next button on it.  I have found several tuts on how to do this when xcode was using the interface builder.  But I can not find one that is for the newest version of xcode.  So I have taken what I have found on the internet and from the Apple dev site and came up with some code.  The only thing is, it doesn't work!  I get an error that says assignment to readonly property on the lines with the inputAcessoryView.  I know that it is probably something simple, but when transfering the code from the previous version to the newer version, I most likely messed something up.  Could someone check out my code and let me know what I did wrong.  Thanks so much. I have included  my .h/.m files

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface keyboardViewController : UIViewController


    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *textField1;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *textField2;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar;

    -(void)resignKeyboard:(id)sender;
    -(void)previousField:(id)sender;
    -(void)nextField:(id)sender;

    @end
```

implimentation

```
    #import "keyboardViewController.h"

    @interface keyboardViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation keyboardViewController
    @synthesize textField1;
    @synthesize textField2;
    @synthesize keyboardToolbar;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        if (keyboardToolbar == nil)
        {
            keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,                            self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)]; 

            UIBarButtonItem *previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"previous" 
                                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                      target:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(previousField:)];
            UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" 
                                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                          target:self 
                                                                          action:@selector(nextField:)];

            UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace) target:nil action:nil];


            UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemDone) target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard:)];



            [keyboardToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:previousButton, nextButton, extraSpace, done, nil]];

            textField1.inputAccessoryView  = keyboardToolbar;
            textField2.inputAccessoryView  = keyboardToolbar;


        }


    }

    -(void) resignKeyboard:(id)sender
    {
        if ([textField1 isFirstResponder])
            [textField1 resignFirstResponder];

        else if ([textField2 isFirstResponder])
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }

    -(void) previousField:(id)sender
    {
        if ([textField1 isFirstResponder])
            [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];

        else if ([textField2 isFirstResponder])
            [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }


    -(void) nextField:(id)sender
    {
        if ([textField1 isFirstResponder])
            [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];

        else if ([textField2 isFirstResponder])
            [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }


    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [self setTextField1:nil];
        [self setTextField2:nil];
        [self setKeyboardToolbar:nil];
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@interface keyboardViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
```

and in .m place instead of this code

```
        textField1.inputAccessoryView  = keyboardToolbar;
        textField2.inputAccessoryView  = keyboardToolbar;
```

paste these code

```
for (id view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [(UITextField *)view setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
    }
}
```

paste this code

```
-(void) resignKeyboard:(id)sender{

         [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

instead of this

```
-(void) resignKeyboard:(id)sender
    {
        if ([textField1 isFirstResponder])
            [textField1 resignFirstResponder];

        else if ([textField2 isFirstResponder])
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

add this code in viewDidLoad method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
-(void)nextField:(id)sender{

    if ([textField1 isFirstResponder]) {

        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
        [nextButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

-(void)previousField:(id)sender{

    if ([textField2 isFirstResponder]) {

        [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(id)sender{

    if ([textField2 isFirstResponder]) {

        [nextButton setEnabled:NO];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else if ([textField1 isFirstResponder]) {

        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Bala, Thanks so much for the reply.  I will try that.  Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: Bala, I changed all the code, thanks!  I get the toolbar now with my buttons previous, next, and done.  The done button works, but not the previous, and next.  Do I need to have an atproperty for them in my header file?  Or is my atselector incorrect.  Thanks again for all you help!!

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
just add this in your viewDidLoad method

Comment: Bala, do I put that after the [super viewDidLoad]; or do I put it in the if statement.  Right now it is in the if statement and I get an error.  Really sorry about this but I am quite the noob.  I am trying to get this app to work so I can get it to my students to help them do some calculations!  Thanks again.

Comment: Bala. Sorry, but that gave me a sigabrt error.  Wait, I just saw some of the other things you posted! Will fix again!!!  UUGGGHHH, I wish I was smarter!

Comment: better i will send you a sample project of it., i use xCode 4.2, and im gonna use ARC in it ., so it wont be a prob for you

Comment: Oh sorry that was my mistake ., i have edited it now , you just check it now

Comment: Bala, the buttons still don't work.  It won't let me use the variable nextbutton in [nextbutton setenable:no] and such because I used it all ready.

Comment: [sample Keyboard with Tool Bar](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60982298/KeyBoardSample.zip)

Comment: Bala,  now I see where I was going wrong.  Thanks so much for helping me learn.

Comment: You should be accepting answer if that is correct, Don't forget !

Answer (score 2):

A UIToolbar is very useful when you are about to add a "done button" when your textfield type is UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad. This is beacause it doesn't have a done button by default. For this you have just to add the following:-

```
    UIToolbar *boolbar = [UIToolbar new];
    boolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [boolbar sizeToFit];


    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnClicked)];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelleftBarButton, nil];
    [leftBarButton release];
    [boolbar setItems:array];

    textField_phnNumber.inputAccessoryView = boolbar;
```

//method performed by selector

-(void)doneBtnClicked{

```
[textField_phnNumber resignFirstResponder];
```

}

**NOTE:-** If you are using UITextField add this in textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate method.

Comment: Arshad,  my done button works now.  But not the other two?  Any idea where I went wrong?  I followed all of Bala's code corrections.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: May be the selector (methods) on those buttons are not working. Try looking into the methods those buttons are performing. Try with debugger and NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates the "Done" button on the **right** side of UIToolbar above the keyboard:

```
UIToolbar *tbAboveKeyboard = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
tbAboveKeyboard.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[tbAboveKeyboard sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:)];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, rightBarButton, nil];
[rightBarButton release];
[tbAboveKeyboard setItems:array];

yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = tbAboveKeyboard;
[tbAboveKeyboard release];
```

...

```
- (void)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [searchTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Can someone translate the answer to swift code?